# Problems regarding the ratio of two definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

These are two interesting problems:

(1) Find the ratio of $\int_0^1 (1-t^4)^{-0.5} \,dt$ and $\int_0^1 (1+t^4)^{-0.5} \,dt$

(2) Find the ratio of $\int_0^x e^{xt-t^2} \,dt$ and $\int_0^x e^{\frac{-t^2}4} \,dt$

Both are not supposed to be solved via solving individual integrals.

I also know that the answer to (2) is $e^{\frac{x^2}4}$, but how it is arrived I am confused.

Furthermore, what's the general way of solving problems like these, the fraction of two definite integrals with same upper and lower limits?

I thank in advance any help I receive!

Comment: (1) note that $t$ has nothing to do with $x$.  (2) complete the square in $xt-t^2$.

Comment: But the first example is strange, the integrating variable $x$ does not appear in the integral, so you are integrating a constant (with respect to $x$). The second one is wrong, because the upper limit cannot be the integrating variable.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistyping: in (1) two integrals are with respect to t, not x. I have already edited it.

Comment: The first problem involves elliptic ingtegrals and I think Euler solved it long back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the change of variable formula, respectively $t=\sin u$ and $t=\tan u$:
   \begin{align}
    &\int_0^1{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}\text{d}t}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /2}{\dfrac{\cos u}{\sqrt{1-\sin ^4u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /2}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin ^2u}}\text{d}u},
   \end{align}
   \begin{align}
    &\int_0^1{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\text{d}t}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{\sec ^2u}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^4u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin ^4u+\cos ^4u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin ^4u+\cos ^4u+2\sin ^2u\cos ^2u-2\sin ^2u\cos ^2u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left( \sin ^2u+\cos ^2u \right) ^2-\frac{1}{2}\sin ^22u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin ^22u+\cos ^22u-\frac{1}{2}\sin ^22u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /4}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos ^22u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /2}{\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos ^2u}}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\int_0^{\pi /2}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\left( 1+\sin ^2u \right)}}\text{d}u}.
   \end{align}
   The ratio is $\sqrt{2}$.
2. Use the change of variable formula $t-\frac x2=\frac u2$, thus $\text{d}t=\frac 12\text{d}u$:
   \begin{align}
    &\int_0^x{\text{e}^{xt-t^2}\text{d}t}\\
    =&\int_0^x{\text{e}^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\text{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{4}+xt-t^2}}\text{d}t\\
    =&\text{e}^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\int_0^x{\text{e}^{-\left( t-\frac{x}{2} \right) ^2}}\text{d}t\\
    =&\text{e}^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\int_{-x}^x{\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}\dfrac{1}{2}\text{d}u}\\
    =&\text{e}^{\frac{x^2}{4}}\int_0^x{\text{e}^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}\text{d}u}.
   \end{align}